# using List.Add() method is breaking my code out of a foreach loops

Tags: c#, list, foreach, linq-to-xml

So, essentially, I'm running into an interesting issue where, when the call to the "`CreateXML()`" function in the following code is made, an xelement is created as intended, but then, when I attempt to add it to a collection of xeleents, instead of continuing the foreach loop from which the call to "`CreateXML()`" originated, the foreach loop is broken out of, and a call is made to "`WriteXML()`". Additionally, though an XElement is created and populated, it is not added to the List. [for clarification, the foreach loops I am referring to live in the "`ParseDoc()`" method]

```
    private List<XElement> _xelemlist;
    private void WriteXml()
    {
        XElement head = new XElement("header", new XAttribute("headerattributename", "attribute"));
        foreach (XElement xelem in _xelemlist)
        {
            head.Add(xelem);
        }
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        doc.Add(head);

    }
    private void CreateXML(string attname, string att)
    {
        XElement xelem = new XElement("name", new XElement("child", new XAttribute(attname, att), segment));
        _xelemlist.Add(xelem);
    }
    private void ExtractSegment(HtmlNode node)
    {
        HtmlAttribute[] segatts = node.Attributes.ToArray();
        string attname = segatts[0].Value.ToString();
        string att = node.InnerText.ToString();
        CreateXML(attname, att);
    }
    private HtmlDocument ParseDoc(HtmlDocument document)
    {
        try
        {
            HtmlNode root = document.DocumentNode.FirstChild;
            foreach (HtmlNode childnode1 in root.SelectNodes(".//child1"))
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode childnode2 in node.SelectNodes(".//child2"))
                {
                    ExtractSegment(childnode2);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        WriteXml();
        return document;
    }
```

When I comment out the "`List.Add()`" in "`CreateXML()`" and step through the code, the foreach loop is not broken out of after the first iteration, and the code works properly.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong (And yes, the code is instantiated by a public member, don't worry: I am only posting the relevant internal methods to my problem)... if anyone has come across this sort of behavior before, I would really appreciate a push in the right direction to attempt to correct it... Sepcifically: is the problem just poor coding, or is this behavior a result of a property of one of the methods/libraries I am using?

**One Caveat**: I know that I am using HTMLAgilityPack to parse a file and extract information, but a requirement on this code forces me to use XDocument to write said information... don't ask me why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

This, for starters:

```
catch (Exception e) { }
```

That's stopping you from seeing what on earth's going on. I strongly suspect you've got a `NullReferenceException` due to `_xelemlist` being null, but that's a *secondary* problem. The main problem is that by pretending everything's fine **whatever happens**, with no logging whatsoever, the only way of getting anywhere is by debugging, and that's an awful experience when you don't need to go through it.

It's *extremely rarely* a good idea catch exceptions and swallow them without any logging at all. It's almost *never* a good idea to do that with `Exception`.

Whenever you have a problem which is difficult to diagnose, improve your diagnostic capabilities first. That way, when you *next* run into a problem, it'll be easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `List` this way,

```
private List<XElement> _xelemlist = new List<XElement>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach loop, you are attempting to use `XElement head` as a list of XElements when you `add()` to it.  This should probably be a list of XElements?

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest switching to using [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)?

Here is some sample code which I have written for work (changed to protect my work :D), and we are using it rather well.

Code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode root;
if(File.Exists(path + "\\MyXmlFile.xml"))
{
    doc.Load(path + "\\MyXmlFile.xml");
    root = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Library");
}
else
{    
    XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
    doc.AppendChild(dec);
    root = doc.CreateElement("Library");
    doc.AppendChild(root);
}

XmlElement book = doc.CreateElement("Book");
XmlElement title = doc.CreateElement("Title");
XmlElement author = doc.CreateElement("Author");
XmlElement isbn = doc.CreateElement("ISBN");

title.InnerText = "Title of a Book";
author.InnerText = "Some Author";
isbn.InnerText = "RandomNumbers";

book.AppendChild(title);
book.AppendChild(author);
book.AppendChild(isbn);
root.AppendChild(book);

doc.Save(path + "\\MyXmlFile.xml");
```